# Why textAlign: 'justify' increases letter spacing in some rows

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using react-native for creating mobile app and I want to make the text justified within the  element.
It works well in most places, but I noticed that in some rows it increasing not only space between words, but between letters as well. 
And it looks strange.
Something like this:

```
Lorem        Ipsum        is       simply   -> in most rows (like I want)
L o r e m   I p s u m   i s   s i m p l y   -> in some rows
```

Who knows why it happens?

Comment: That's exactly what justify does: [w3school says](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp): Stretches the lines so that each line has equal width (like in newspapers and magazines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-formatting):

> If [`text-align`] has the value 'justify', the user agent may stretch spaces **and words** in inline boxes (but not inline-table and inline-block boxes) as well.

*(my emphasis)*

So not just spaces between words, but words themselves can be stretched to fill the space. The algorithm the browser uses to decide where to add the padding (between words, within words, or a combination) is browser-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Justify means: fillup from left to right, it'll space out the wording / letters in a line until it feels up...

Comment: this still doesn't explain why it has to expand letter spacing when word spacing does the trick alone plus it looks better. This seems like a bug instead.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's what "justify" means in typesetting.  It means both the left and right side of every line are aligned.  The only way to reliably do that without splitting words is to mess with the letter kerning.  This is frequently used in column based layouts like a newspaper.

Comment: It's not the *only*  way  but rather a compromise between good look and CPU effort. Modern professional printing methods even vary the font width (i.e. width of characters) up or down to achieve proper alignment without too obvious white space in the line.

Comment: Good to know, I've not seen that approach before.