# react native text align by justify adds whitespace between letters

Tags: react-native, text, text-align, react-native-text

when using

```
text-align: justify
```

on react native it adds whitespace between the letters as well for some reason and is supposted to just add whitespace between words

image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZor0.png

i have tried removing letter-spacing but it just makes it worst because the whitespace between letters is based on the screen size so it just makes the text look bad on other devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this how justify work you can check this old answer for more details about why/how it's works like that in react native from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42226507/why-textalign-justify-increases-letter-spacing-in-some-rows).